# Page Layout HTML5

Tags: css, html, wordpress, layout

I'm trying to create My first Wordpress theme , for my pesonnel Blog , and this's how it should be looking :  [image]
 I'm using Grid960, Also should I put the articals in One Section or the opposite
And this's my Page Layout , Structre, I want to Know if it's correct :

```
<body class="container_12"> 
    <nav>           
    </nav>  
         <article 1>
            <h2></h2>
            <p</p>
            <a href="#"> Show More</a>          
          </article>
                  <article 2>
            <h2></h2>
            <p</p>
            <a href="#"> Show More</a>          
          </article>
    <aside>
        <section> 
        <h4></h4>
        </section>
        <section> 
        <h4></h4>
            </section>
    </aside>
       <footer>
       </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: <article 1> is invalid HTML5 markup so is `<article 2>` Remove the numbers. What tag is this `<p</p>`?

Comment: Also read the *usage notes* here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section

Comment: I know I have Added "1 an 2" to article To means that's the first article and the second , and for <p</p> it's just mistake because I have deleted the text to minimize my code that's All . So is my Page Layout Valide or should I change the structre

Comment: Made no sense at all cause than we would expect `1` and `2` under your `<section>` tags aswell, even than we would notify you about your typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a couple paragraph tags like this `<p</p>` , when they should be `<p></p>`

Also, you had `<article 1> <article 2>` which is not correct. Think of the article tags just like p tags. Only the word article can go inbetween the `<>` , like this `<article>` .. However, more things can go inbetween it if you use valid syntax.

For example

This is valid syntax

```
<article class="article1" id="firstarticle" style="background: blue;"> </article>
```

The following examples are  not valid

```
<article 3>
<article someword anotherword>
<article class=article1>
```

---

Your code corrected

```
<body class="container_12"> 
    <nav>           
    </nav>  
         <article class="article1">
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>
            <a href="#"> Show More</a>          
          </article>
                  <article class="article2">
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>
            <a href="#"> Show More</a>          
          </article>
    <aside>
        <section> 
        <h4></h4>
        </section>
        <section> 
        <h4></h4>
            </section>
    </aside>
       <footer>
       </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I know I have Added "1 an 2" to article To means that's the first article and the second , and for <p</p> it's just mistake because I have deleted the text to minimize my code that's All . So is my Page Layout Valide or should I change the structre

Comment: Yep, it's valid html all right. Make sure you have the <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>SomeTitleWords</title></head> tags before body though.. If your using wordpress its probably in a separate file called header.php. Then just after </body> you need </html>, but that is likely already in the footer.php.